# React native drawer with login page functionality

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, navigator

I have used `Navigator` in react native to navigate between two screens.
Initial route for my application is `LoginPage`. After Login successfully, I have to open `Dashboard` (i.e `HomePage` Screen) with `Navigation drawer`.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{id: 'LoginPage'}}
        renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}/>
    );
  }

  navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'LoginPage':
        return (<LoginPage navigator={navigator} title="Login Page"/>);
      case 'HomePage':
        return (<HomePage navigator={navigator} title="Home Page" />);
    }
  }
}
```

On Login button press, user will be redirected to Dashboard(HomePage.js)

**LoginPage.js**

```
onLoginPress(){
this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'HomePage'
    })
}
```

then how to add drawer on `HomePage.js`.
Please refer following link for drawer: [Navigation Drawer](http://caroaguilar.com/post/react-native-navigation-tutorial/)

Comment: awaiting the same

Comment: @SSS: you can refer following for solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739883/how-to-set-react-native-drawer-visible-only-to-dashboard-after-login-in-react